# 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd', because the root element of the document is not <xsd:schema>

Tags: spring-batch

While starting my application am getting the following Error.

> WARNING: Ignored XML validation warning
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 77; schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.warning(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:99)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:433)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:347)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaErr(XSDHandler.java:4166

Comment: please suggest any one.

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is this line doesn't recognize the XML header, specifically in the namespace's part. Or you have an error on the line that you describe or must successfully add the required package in your package manager(maven, gradle).
Try adding these lines to your pom.xml and try after to do a mvn clean install

```
<properties>
    <spring.batch.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>  
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
</dependency>
```